# Accessing 'as' controller property from external Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have Javscript mapping component which on addition to a map, I would like to get a color preference from an Angular 1.5 'as' controller which drives user preferences.

So may controller code looks like:

```
app.controller('PreferenceController', function($http, $httpParamSerializer) {

  this.preferredBoundaryColorHex = '#007fff';
  ...
```

And in the html is:

```
<div ng-controller="PreferenceController as pref">
... preference html
</div>
```

How to I get a reference to the controller from outside Angular? My understanding is that the preference is just an object property on the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods)

```
var pref = angular.element(jsReferenceToElement).controller();
var colour = pref.preferredBoundaryColorHex;
```

Where `jsReferenceToElement` is the return value from something like `getElementById` or `querySelector`.

Comment: Thankyou. Could you clarify what jsReferenceToElement is? I am using a `<body ng-app="mainMap"> ` body tag

Comment: @timbo I've added some more info. You'll need some way to identify the element in question. I'd go with adding an `id` attribute and using `document.getElementById`